# jquery slider viewport width

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I am testing a jquery full width slider and the code is below:

```
var width = $(window).width();
console.log('width 1 = '+width);
var width = window.innerWidth;
console.log('width 2 = '+width);
var width = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth;
console.log('width 3 = '+width);

var animationSpeed = 1000;
var pause = 2000;
var currentSlide = 1;

//cache DOM elements
var $slider = $('#slider');
var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
var $slides = $('.slide', $slider);

var interval;

function startSlider() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
            if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                currentSlide = 1;
                $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
            }
        });
    }, pause);
}
function pauseSlider() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}

$slideContainer
    .on('mouseenter', pauseSlider)
    .on('mouseleave', startSlider);

startSlider();
```

The html is:

```
<div id="slider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide slide1"><img src="<?php echo base_url('public/img/carousel/carousel-1.jpg'); ?>" alt=""></li>
    <li class="slide slide2"><img src="<?php echo base_url('public/img/carousel/carousel-2.jpg'); ?>"</li>
    <li class="slide slide3"><img src="<?php echo base_url('public/img/carousel/carousel-3.jpg'); ?>"</li>
    <li class="slide slide4"><img src="<?php echo base_url('public/img/carousel/carousel-4.jpg'); ?>"</li>
    <li class="slide slide5"><img src="<?php echo base_url('public/img/carousel/carousel-5.jpg'); ?>"</li>
    <li class="slide slide6"><img src="<?php echo base_url('public/img/carousel/carousel-1.jpg'); ?>"</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This works fine except for a problem with viewport width. There is an issue with the vertical scrollbar and if the width is wrong, obviously the slide moves laterally by an incorrect amount. I am checking 'width' using console log (see code above) and 'width 1' and 'width 3' give the same width that works OK in, say, Waterfox. However in, say, Chrome and Firefox it is too small by 17px (the width of the vertical scrollbar). But if I use 'width 2' which works in Chrome and Firefox, it is too big for Waterfox by again 17px. I have found a number of posts referring to this but they either suggest things I am already doing but don't work or leave it unresolved. Can anyone suggest a simple fix?

Comment: can you please add full code with html?

Comment: TY for responding. HTML added